Using props to pass a ref object down to child component
Is it safe to do this:
function Parent() {
  const myRef = useRef([1, 2, 3]);
  console.log("parent: " + myRef.current);
  return <Child myList={myRef.current} />;
}

function Child({ myList }) {
  const [currInt, setCurrInt] = useState(4);
  console.log("child: " + myList);
  return (
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        myList.push(currInt);
        setCurrInt((n) => n + 1);
      }}
    />
  );
}

Output:
parent: 1,2,3
child: 1,2,3
<click>
child: 1,2,3,4
<click>
child: 1,2,3,4,5
...


I know the parent won't rerender upon updates of myList and that is the expected behavior.
I just wonder if this goes against any kind of React principles or could break in the future.
Previously I had stored the initial list passed down from Parent in another ref inside the Child component and this worked as well. However, it does not seem to be necessary if I can just mutated the parent ref object.

No, never directly alter a ref like that.

Could you provide more context as to why not?

Why it's feasible
Actually, if you consider this situation purely from a JavaScript perspective, there's no issue because the Child and Parent components share the same object. This object's memory address remains unchanged upon the Parent's re-render, thanks to the use of useRef.
Why not
However, adopting this approach may lead to confusion regarding the data flow. In React, I recommend employing pure functions to ensure a clear and predictable data stream. It's advisable to avoid ambiguous data transfers as much as possible. I believe that the key to efficient development lies in making the codebase easily maintainable and update-friendly.
Summary
Although this violates some of React's core principles, such as data flowing down from parent to child, this capability is necessary in certain scenarios. Therefore, it exists as an escape hatch.

Please add more reference to the answer by adding a code snippet or links to some supporting documentation.

Did you generate this answer using a tool like ChatGPT?

it's a principle, not code question.

To get this done you need to wrap the Child inside forwardRef & pass the take ref object as a prop.
& for advance functionality you can use useImperativeHandle hooks.
https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef
https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle

I have been using forwardRef in the past to pass a ref from the child (e.g. DOM element) up to the parent. However, this is not the usecase I'm describing here

So, can you describe in detail, what is it you want.
